# How do I get latex styling in a html page I view offline?

Tags: html, css, latex, pdflatex

I copied the following page (which contains math notation) from the web:

https://brilliant.org/wiki/sphere-packing/

It contains notation such as:  `\(\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\)`

If I just view this page offline (by saving it first to my laptop), the CSS can't refer to whatever extra libraries are needed (I think it needs tex or latex) to make the notation legible.
Is there a way to download some extra file from the web and link to it so I can read documents like this on an offline setting?